# Can it Work to Run PCA only on a Subset of Highly Correlated Predictors prior to Regularization? (Cox)

Tags: correlation, pca, cox-model, regularization

I'm running Cox-LASSO (using `glmnet` [as explained by Tay et al](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/Coxnet.html)) on about 50 variables  with about 300 observations. The variables fit into different categories like "clinical scales" or "risk measures".

One category of variables is highly correlated to each other and only each other. It's about 12 of them. My thinking is: these are in a similar category, so if I run PCA on them only, the loss of interpretability wouldn't be so bad. I would like to do PCA on that subset, and then run LASSO on a set of variables that is the 1-2 principal components, plus the other predictors as-is... is this a bad idea?

Comment: In principle, yes, you can do that. However, 300 observations on 38 variables plus 1-2 PCs is still a hugely overparameterized situation. Even your lasso will probably be highly variable. It's not a magic wand.

Comment: In a Cox model, it's the number of events, not the number of observations, that limits model quality. See Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/).

Comment: @StephanKolassa unfortunately the field experts want all the variables considered in the selection process. Is there a better way than LASSO to narrow it down?

Comment: The best way would be to leverage domain knowledge to reduce the model beforehand. Or alternatively, to collect more data (which I assume is not possible because of cost). You can absolutely use a regularization technique such as the lasso, just be aware that it is not magic. I would suggest you bootstrap your model, just to get an idea of its variability. Are you modeling for prediction or for inference?

Comment: @StephanKolassa thank you. The research wants to prove that inclusion of certain covariates "improves prediction".

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Then sure, go ahead and assess your model on a holdout set, or in a cross-validation setup and see whether it improves on some benchmark prediction model. (I was afraid you were going to do significance testing. That is quite hard in regularized models.) Just be aware that your predictions and your predictive performance will still be highly variable.

Comment: @StephanKolassa thank you -- I should also clarify that I am not doing parameter estimates or p values based on regularization. I'm using regularization to delete variables, and then fitting a standard Cox Model on what's left.